# Is the NVIDIA GeForce 9400M on the MacBook Pro good for gaming?

Tags: macbook-pro, games, gpu

I want to know what kind of games can I play with my MacBook Pro before I purchase them. Can I play something beyond Bejeweled? Type of games that I am interested in playing:

- Call of Duty
- Counter Strike Source
- Civilization

Comment: Note that some MacBook Pros also have a 9600M GT graphics card. You can find out if yours does by going to Energy Saver in System Preferences and checking for a group of bubbles that gives you a choice between "Better Battery Life" and "Higher Performance".

Answer (score 1):

I have a 5,2 MacBook with that Nvidia chip. Being the Civ fan that I am, I used to Bootcamp and *try* to play Civ IV: BTS but it wasn't pretty. I suppose if you turned the graphics settings way down to the minimum you may have some luck.

Civ V. No hope at all.

Comment: No worries mate.

Answer (score 0):

Counter Strike Source will have little to no trouble because the Source Engine relies more on the CPU than GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had crysis, and crysis 2 running, with playable FPS. Crank down the resolution.